# Magento API Ignores Attributes on Product-Creation

Tags: php, magento, soap

I'm passing "color" and "size" within the attributes dictionary in to the product-create API using the XML-RPC (Magenta 1.x) interface. For the purpose of experimentation, there is exactly one attribute-type, and it's being passed. The attributes are valid and the values being passed are defined as valid options for those attributes.

Even though the product is being created, the attributes are discarded. I placed some debugging statements in the code, and the attributes are being read and assigned on the model without a problem, but the save() is ignoring them. I guess the question is whether the attributes are supposed to be stored as scalars directly on the model or if they should be passed in such a way as to be passed differently.

Does anyone have any idea about a fix for this? I can create a product by hand with these attributes without a problem.

General structure of the API call:

```
def create_simple_product(
        self, attribute_set_id, sku, catalog_product_create_entity, 
        attributes={}):
    cpce_dict = \
        ma.utility.get_dict_from_named_tuple(
            catalog_product_create_entity)

    if attributes:
        cpce_dict['additional_attributes'] = { 
            'single_data': attributes,
        }

    product_id = \
        self.magento.catalog_product.create(
            'simple', 
            attribute_set_id, 
            sku, 
            cpce_dict)
```

Comment: Show some code, please.

Comment: @paskl I edited the question, but, since this is an API/understanding problem, not a coding problem, I didn't originally think it'd help.